# Ideas how to create oldschool gold logo similar to Labyrinth

Tags: fonts, logo

I need to create Labyrinth style logo, but with the text "Puzzled Pint" for the small event I'm hosting. It should be similar to this:[image: Labyrinth logo]

Does anyone have any tutorial? Or even some advice?

I extracted the gradient and now I'm looking for the font, but I have no idea what to do with the edges when I finally find the font. Any tutorial or advice?

edit: I'm using GIMP

Comment: Which software do you have access to?

Comment: There are many tutorials on the web if you search for golden text or gold effect. It would be easier if you told us what software are you planning to use for this.

Answer (score 3):

Photoshop:

The gloss isn't only a gradient, it has a darker shape to make an illusion of curved surface and a reflection from the horizon.

I skip the colors and goto the edges of the letters, as asked.

[image]

In the bottom there's a black copy, only shifted a little down and to the right

Layer style Bevel&Emboss is applied to make the bevelled edges. All settings are critical. You may need to play a while until the right combination is found.

Bevel&Emboss with weird settings is often used to create metallic gloss. It can make plausible large gradients with very little work. Here's a coloring example, where all gradients are generated with Bevel&Emboss

[image]

There is 2 extra embossed layers with weird settings. The letters were copied to them with contracted selection to leave the edges visible in layer "Puzzle". Layer Interior Lower is clipped at mid height with eraser to create the dark curved edge.

On the top there's adjustment layer Curves to stretch the contrast.

Beware: Option global light means that you adjust every bevelled object in the current work.

Comment: *wave* youre alive! hope all is well

Comment: woops, it was. my mistake! (ill delete all of these later today)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to Photoshop, then it could be achieved using layers and layer effects.

Here are a bunch of layer effects I added, a Bevel & Emboss effect, three Stroke effects, a Gradient Overlay, and Drop shadow. Your example is above for comparison.  I also got the letters to overlap by adjusting the kerning.

[image]

As for the bevelled inside of the letters, you could draw some shapes and fill them with yellow.

[image]

If you don't have Photoshop, there's a Layer Effects plugin for the free image editor GIMP, which could be used similarly.

**Update:** Since you mentioned GIMP is the software you have, take a look at the Gold Text tutorial on the GIMP website: https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Golden_Text/.

I made this in GIMP using similar techniques, however I used the bump map filter rather than the lighting filter, plus a bit warping of the underlying gradient with the Warp Transform tool.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the style for your new wording you have 2 options (that I can think of).

1. You trace the font manually with the pen tool on illustrator and match the gradient.
2. If you find a very similar font but with sharp edges the type away, then expand the text (let me know if you need details where to find that option). Once the text is expanded add pen point with the pen tool and round the borders.

It looks like a huge task but if you got the time you'll get it done in no time.

Good Luck!